Using Lightning record form I want to add divider after each field like salesforce standard page
I want to add divider after each field in lightning record view form.
HTML:
<lightning-record-view-form
    object-api-name={object} 
    record-id={recordId}
    onerror={handleError}>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <template for:each={fields} for:item="field">
            <div key={field} class={columSize}>
                <lightning-output-field field-name={field}></lightning-output-field>
                <hr class="field-divider"/>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>

</lightning-record-view-form> 

CSS:
.field-divider {
    border: 0;
    border-top: 0.031rem solid #d8dde6; 
    margin: -0.08rem 0; 
}

alignment of divider is not setting correctly  because getting  dynamic fields values.
